# SUM query on millions of records is slow even with indexes, how can I optimize?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I have a database table with about 3.5 million records.  The table holds contract data records, with an amount, a date, and some IDs related to other tables (VendorId, AgencyId, StateId), this is the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VendorContracts]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,   
    [ContractDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ContractAmount] [decimal](19, 4) NULL, 
    [VendorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AgencyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StateId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_VendorContracts] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a page on my site where I'd like users to be able to select a vendor, and see the total amount of contract amounts, split by state.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(ContractAmount), StateId
FROM [dbo].[VendorContracts]
WHERE VendorId = '...'
GROUP BY StateId
```

And I created this index to help with that:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_VendorContracts_VendorId] ON [dbo].[VendorContracts]
(
    [VendorId] ASC
)
INCLUDE([Id],[StateId],[ContractAmount],[ContractDate],[AgencyId]) 
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
```

This works great for most my vendors, I can get results back fairly quickly in a second or two. But there are a couple vendors that each have about 1 million records though, and those take quite a while, usually a few minutes.

So I was wondering if there's any way to optimize further, by modifying my index? Or any other way?

Or am I maybe going about this wrong? Not sure if running such huge `SUM` queries on 1 million records is just not a great way to do this. Records aren't added very frequently to this table, we maybe add a few thousand once or twice a month, so I was thinking of maybe having a nightly process that would grab the `SUM` data and store them in a separate table, and then query that when I need to run reports.

Comment: There is never a reason to include the PK value in any index. I will argue that your PK is not very helpful and is contributing to your general inefficiency - a very different question. You need an index on <VendorId, StateId> that includes ContractAmount for this specific query. Depending on your usage of this table, there are likely better choices for clustering. I suspect you need to pay more attention to your datatypes. ContractDate is not likely to need a time portion. CreateBy is never going to have 2Gb characters. Etc.

Comment: The indexed view is another approach. But be warned - nothing is free and that materialization must be maintained during DML statements. And you might need to write specific code to take advantage of it based on your edition. The disadvantage of the view is that it will not be useful for queries that are similar to the one you have now - e.g., when you need to select actual rows for a specific vendor and state.

Comment: @SMor - thank you for the suggestions, I can work on updating my indexes and datatypes. I'm admittedly very novice when it comes to SQL database indexes/optimizations/etc, which I'm finding out I need to learn as I deal with this massive table :)

Answer (score 4):

You should take the query...

```
SELECT SUM(ContractAmount) AS TotalContractAmount,
       VendorId,
       StateId
FROM   [dbo].[VendorContracts]
GROUP  BY VendorId,
          StateId
```

... and make it into an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) so the results are pre-calculated and maintained automatically by the system (with unique clustered index on `VendorId, StateId`).

Indexed views can have overhead for data modifications but you say

> Records aren't added very frequently to this table, we maybe add a
> few thousand once or twice a month,

SQL Server should do the indexed view matching automatically on Azure SQL database and recognize that the original query can be served by an indexed view.

If you find this matching does not happen (verify the execution plan) then you may need to resort to selecting from the indexed view explicitly and using a `NOEXPAND` hint.

Comment: Yes, It is an Azure SQL database. I've noticed some strangeness where the first time I run the query, it's slow, and then very fast every time after that for the VendorId I pass as a parameter. Could that be Azure creating an indexed view automatically?

Comment: Thanks Martin, so just to confirm, I would create an indexed view that contains that data for all vendors, and then query against that view with the specific VendorId I need?

Comment: @Steven - No. Azure won't create it automatically - probably the difference is from reading physical pages from disc vs data already in the buffer cache.

Comment: And RE: "Just to confirm" - yes that would give the best performance for this specific query. Smor does make a good point that your existing index (`IX_VendorContracts_VendorId`) is not the most optimal choice though. `StateId` should be the secondary key column to avoid any requirement to sort or hash to do the grouping. You may want to try with that first. It would still need to collapse the millions of rows for large vendors down to 50 or so at run time which the indexed view avoids

Comment: Okay thanks, I can add that `StateId` column to the index instead of just being an `INCLUDE`. I was under the impression that only columns to be filtered on should be on the index, which is why I only included `VendorId` - but I assume since I'm doing a `GROUP BY` on `StateId` it should be included as well?

Comment: @Steven - An index on `(VendorId, StateId) INCLUDE (ContractAmount)` could be seeked into to do an equality on `VendorId`. When StateId is added as a secondary key column then within each VendorId the results are sorted by `StateId` (so effectively already ordered by group) this can be fed into a stream aggregate operator that calculates the per group totals for each group in turn.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an operational database system where you want to do some reporting, then you should consider using a columnstore index in Azure SQL DB.  It supports a clustered and non-clustered columnstore.  Columnstores are great for reporting/analytics both because they are highly compressed compared to B-Trees/Heaps and because there is an optimized execution engine called batch mode that is substantially more efficient for queries over lots of rows like your report query.

You can read about the syntax at [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Without knowing more about your workload, I can't say for sure whether you should use clustered or non-clustered.  However, it is relatively easy to try non-clustered to see if it helps your app.  While indexed views can be used to make a specific query pattern go faster, it does have some limitations - for example, if you have a lot of updates happening on your main table, those update queries now have to take locks on both the main table + indexes as well of those on the indexed view.  This can potentially cause blocking on locks.  Try batch mode via a non-clustered columnstore index (you will want to move to compat mode 150 for the latest/greatest performance enhancements if you have not) to see if this solves your problem.